# Docker-desktop recreates deleted folder in WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a wierd issue. I noticed lately that some of the folders I had deleted in my WSL2 Ubuntu distribution on Windows 11 were still there after I rebooted my PC. The folder are empty but no matter what I do they always come back after every reboot. I installed `loggedfs` to see what was going on and here are the logs:

```
2022-06-28 13:47:22,970 INFO [default] LoggedFS not running as a daemon
2022-06-28 13:47:22,970 INFO [default] LoggedFS running as a public filesystem
2022-06-28 13:47:22,970 INFO [default] LoggedFS starting at /home/user/dev/.
2022-06-28 13:47:22,970 INFO [default] chdir to /home/user/dev/
2022-06-28 13:47:24,105 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/ {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,105 ERROR [default] getattr /home/user/dev/deleted_folder {FAILURE} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/ {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 ERROR [default] getattr /home/user/dev/deleted_folder {FAILURE} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/ {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/ {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 ERROR [default] getattr /home/user/dev/deleted_folder {FAILURE} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,106 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/ {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,107 INFO [default] mkdir /home/user/dev/deleted_folder 755 {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
2022-06-28 13:47:24,107 INFO [default] getattr /home/user/dev/deleted_folder {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]
```

You can clearly see Docker desktop tries to getattr of my deleted_folder (but fails because it no longer exists):

`2022-06-28 13:47:24,105 ERROR [default] getattr /home/user/dev/deleted_folder {FAILURE} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]`

So then it recreates the folder:

`2022-06-28 13:47:24,107 INFO [default] mkdir /home/user/dev/deleted_folder 755 {SUCCESS} [ pid = 151 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy uid = 0 ]`

It doesn't seem to happen with every folders so I'm confused what might be causing this issue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070142/zombie-folders-coming-back-from-the-dead-with-docker-running-on-wsl2), I ran Docker Desktop troubleshoot and selected "Purge data" on WSL2. It worked, but I still have no idea what the underlying issue is though.

Comment: +1 You probably had a case where Windows NTFS and the shadow Linux file-system went out of phase. Purge data probably got rid of the shadow Linux file-system so it could restart again.

Comment: So glad to hear you figured it out.  That's some good troubleshooting!  I would *not* have thought of using `loggedfs`, but I'll have to add that to my toolbox.  Thanks!